# inheritance properties with <li> in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reproduce a website in HTML et css. In my code, I have differents lists, each on with differents css properties. In my browser, the properties are mixed, and I can't understand...
My html code :

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///my css !/css/odpf.css" >

        <title>Olympiades</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="barre_haut">
            </div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="container bg-white">
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu_haut" class="nav flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-end">
                            <li id="menu_haut" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Recherche</a></li>
                            <li id="menu_haut" class="nav-item menurouge"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Connexion</a></li>
                            <li id="menu_haut" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Mon compte</a></li>
                            <li id="menu_haut" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Presse</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-4 bg-white"><div class="position-absolute" style="bottom:0px; left:35px"><img src="https://odpf.org/templates/odpftemplate/img/site-logo-398x106.png" alt="Logo Olympiades" style="width:100%; height:auto"></div></div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 bg-white"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-5 bg-white pr-0"><img src="https://odpf.org/templates/odpftemplate/img/home-rightcol-top2.png" alt="image_en_tete" style="width:100%; height:auto"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-gche-accueil ">
                                <div class="row px-3 pb-0">
                                    <img src="https://odpf.org/images/odpf_slider_home_08.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto">
                                    <div class="menugche">
                                        <h3 class="mt-1">les olympiades de physique france</h3>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="menugche"><a href="#">C'est quoi ?</a></li>
                                            <li class="menugche">Comment ça se passe ?</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h3 class="mt-1">Revivez les éditions passées</h3>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="menugche">Archives</li>
                                            <li class="menugche">Les mémoires</li>
                                            <li class="menugche">Colloque de la 20ème édition</li>
                                               </ul>
                                      </div>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="barre_bas">
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And my css :

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700);
    body {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      background: url('../images/bg-home.png') no-repeat center fixed; 
      background-size: cover;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:black;
    }
    .menurouge {
      background-color: #b1191d;
      color: white;
    }
    .menurouge a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:white;
    }
    .fondnoir {
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
    }
    /* Header */
    #barre_haut {
      background-color: black;
      height: 16px;
      width: 100%;
      }
    #wrapper {
      background-color: #555f69;
      /*position: relative;
      top:16px;*/
      height: 35px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      }
    .container {
      width:100%;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    @media (min-width: 576px){
        .container {
            max-width: 540px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 786px){
        .container {
            max-width: 720px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px){
        .container {
            max-width: 960px;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px){
          .container {
            max-width: 960px;
   }
    
   #barre_bas {
     clear: both;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #555f69;
     height: 10px;
   }
   #menu_haut { 
     height: 35px;
     background-color: white;
     color: black;
     font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 300;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     list-style-type: none;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
   
    .col-gche-accueil {
     background-color: black;
     width: 100%;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     padding: 46px 20px 20px;
   }
   .col-gche-accueil::before {
     content: ' ';
     background: url('https://odpf.org/templates/odpftemplate/img/home-leftcol-top.png') no-repeat;
     width: 100%;
     height: 101px;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 10;
   }
   .menugche h3 {
     font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
     font-size: 40px;
     line-height:43px;
     font-weight: 300;
     color: #ffffff;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     margin: 14px 0 8px; 
   }
   .menugche ul li:before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
   }
   .menugche ul li:after {
     content: '';
     display: table;
     clear: both;
   }
   .menugche ul,li,a {
     background-color: #b1191d;
     color: #ffffff;
     display: block;
     font-size: 18px;
     line-height: 20px;
     list-style-type: none;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 3px 0 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
```

And, tipycally, my menu line in beginning should be black on withe, in 12, and it appears withe on red, in 20 with properties defined by "menugche"....

What's wrong in my head ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Well of course that second LI has a red-ish background - because it has the class `menurouge`, via which you apply this. Not sure where the mystery in that is supposed to lie now?

Comment: @CBroe The mistery, for me, is that the first menu (menu-haut) doesn't  refer to menurouge. In the "Developer tools" of my browser, the properties of the two menus appear mixed, not in cascade !

Comment: There are a few settings I don’t fully understand. For example which elements do these selectors apply to .menugche ul,li,a I can’t see any ul which has a ,menugche an ancestor and did you mean those commas?

Comment: Why should it have to "refer" to that class? The LI _has_ that class, and so the LI itself gets the background color _from_ that class. What does that have to do with the background color of the menu itself?

Comment: @A.Haworth I Think my commas between ul and li, and a are errors.  But, even without, I have the same comportment...

Comment: @CBroe  For me, the menurouge should only be in use with the second item of menu_haut. And the appearance of the entire menu_haut is the appearance of the menugche...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menugche ul,li,a {
```

This defines three separate rules:

- Any `ul` element which is a descendant of an element with the `menugche` class;
- Any `li` element;
- Any `a` element;

I suspect you wanted the rules to be:

- Any `ul` element which is a descendant of an element with the `menugche` class;
- Any `li` element **which is a descendant of an element with the `menugche` class**;
- Any `a` element **which is a descendant of an element with the `menugche` class**;

If that's the case, you'll need to repeat the class name:

```css
.menugche ul, .menugche li, .menugche a {
```

Comment: Many thanks !I undestand something I never have understood !!!